# What is masking here

Tags: python

In the python tutorial:

In interactive mode, the last printed expression is assigned to the variable _. This means that when you are using Python as a desk calculator, it is somewhat easier to continue calculations, for example:

```
>>> tax = 12.5 / 100
>>> price = 100.50
>>> price * tax
12.5625
>>> price + _
113.0625
>>> round(_, 2)
113.06
```

This variable should be treated as read-only by the user. Don’t explicitly assign a value to it — you would create an independent local variable with the same name **masking the built-in variable with its magic behavior**.

What is masking here?

**In general** what is meant by masking or mask variable in python?

THanks

Comment: @Leon I highlighted in bold how my question differs. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable is masked if some other variable with the same name exists, which is preferred. An example is having a global variable x. If you're in a function which also has a local variable x, then the global won't be accessible, without special measures the local variable is preferred whenever you use identifier x inside the function.

It's as if you have two kids in your classroom both called Mary, one of which is closer, and will hear your voice earlier, so always gives the quickest answer. How to give the other girl a chance?

Comment: @JacquesdeHogge thanks, nicely explained. Could you help me in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980136/what-is-the-use-of-mask

Comment: In general masking means 'to (partially) hide', like a mask (partially) hides your face.  A local variable hides a global variable with the same name. With 110011 & 100101, the 100101 acts like a mask, only letting through the first and last 1 of 110011, resulting into 100001. In your other question I believe it's about a document mask, masking out certain fragments or aspects of a document. To mask out means: To leave out. It is a very general term, but I guess this about covers it.

Comment: @JacquesdeHogge thanks, so in general masking is an operation that partially hides some part of your data structure. To do that masking operation you usually have some variable, which is called making variable (sometimes just called mask) which is applied to the original variable through some operation depending on the required task. I guess this is right? thx.

Comment: Hiding (part of) either the contents of your data (bitmask example) or its reachability by name (local variable example)

Comment: @JacquesdeHogge thanks, yes reachability by name in this example, hiding data in the other one.

Answer (score 2):

**Overwriting**/**reassigning** a previously named identifier in a **new scope**

let's look at this code for example

```
def f():
    return 3

def g():
    f = 5
    f()

try:
    print(g())
except TypeError:
    print(f())
```

within the scope of `g`, the identifier `f` has been reassigned from a function that returns an integer, to just an integer. so when you try calling `f` inside of `g` you should get a type error because you can't call an int. however outside of `g`, `f` is still a function that returns 3

the interpreter has its own scope so when you assign `_` to another value, it forgets it's previous functionality in replace of the new value, until you restart the interpreter, or in this special case delete it with the `del` keyword

Comment: Could you once check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980136/what-is-the-use-of-mask Thanks a lot.

Comment: There's a subtle difference between masking and overwriting. In  your example the function will never be accessible anymore. In case of masking the maskee is still there, only not accessible as long as the masker is in scope

Comment: yeah thank you I realized that too late. I need to do more research before I answer a question I think I know the answer to

Comment: Don't be too modest! Many people aren't, and they may get a job while you're better suited.

Answer (score 1):

The `_` is built-in to the interpreter, it has special meaning.  It only acts like a read-only variable. When you read from it, the interpreter replaces it with the last calculated value. If you do something like

```
_ = 1 + 1
```

You are actually creating a new variable named `_` in the current namespace (try running `locals()`function before and after creating the variable). Since there is now a variable with the same name as the interpreter built-in `_` that variable is accessed first when you do subsequent reads, thus hiding the meaning of the built-in, or **masking** it.

You can also do what you're doing with Python built-ins as well, such as defining a function parameter named`int`. In the the local function namespace, if you tried to call the`int()` function on a value, it would attempt to use your parameter`int` as a callable because there is a local variable with that name masking the built-in function `int`. Some IDEs will warn you when you try to do something like this because in practice it is generally a bad idea to mask the name of a built-in like that because you're eliminating the behavior of that  what that symbol is intended for.

Where making comes in its if you do something like

```
val = 20

def do_stuff(val):
    # parameter masks the value defined in outer scope
    print('Value of a inside function: {}'.f format(val))

do_stuff(10)  # prints 10
```

This assigns a variable `val` a value of 20, but when the function `do_stuff` is called it had it's own local variable named`val`. Accessing`val` from within the function will give you the value passed in, 10 in this case, not 20 from the outer variable because the`a` within the function **masks** the one in the outer scope.